# iOS tone generation

Tags: ios, audio, sampling, trigonometry

I'm looking at this [example about sound generation on iOS](http://cocoawithlove.com/2010/10/ios-tone-generator-introduction-to.html) because I need to do something similar but there's some parts I don't understand and I was hoping someone could help me with that.

In this part of the code:

```
    double theta_increment = 2.0 * M_PI * viewController->frequency / viewController->sampleRate;
    // Generate the samples
    for (UInt32 frame = 0; frame < inNumberFrames; frame++) 
    {
        buffer[frame] = sin(theta) * amplitude;

        theta += theta_increment;
        if (theta > 2.0 * M_PI)
        {
            theta -= 2.0 * M_PI;
        }
    }
```

I don't really understand what the `theta += theta_increment;` part is for. To me it makes more sense to do something like this inside the for loop:

```
buffer[frame] = sin(theta_increment * frame);
```

Any idea why that wouldn't work? Also, I have no idea what this part of the code is for: `if (theta > 2.0 * M_PI)` so any explanation on that would be very welcome too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach could be used to create the same result, expressed differently. However, `theta += theta_increment;` will be a simpler expression (to calculate) than what you propose.

The domain of the phase is wrapped to `sin'`s logical parameter domain. This step is really not necessary for short samples. Due to limits in floating point storage, your frequency may eventually vary and ultimately never increment if the value is not wrapped, depending how many samples you generate and whether you use `float` or `double`. Think of it this way: What will happen if you have a *huge* positive floating point number (the value of your phase accumulator) and you attempt to add `0.000004` to it? Floating point error will round it to fit into a float or double and the error will result in phase and ultimately pitch instabilities. For short samples (e.g. some cycles), the wrap wouldn't be needed in this case, but for many many cycles, it serves to stabilize the pitch and phase accumulator over time.

Finally, theta would be used to store the phase ramp's last value, in order to resume generation where it left off in a following render invocation. Without that, the output would restart at 0 at render invocation boundaries, producing very unpleasant noises and the wrong frequencies.

All things considered: It was likely because it was a simple demo, and a fast way to generate the sine in that context. Your approach has some 'costly' conversions, but it is branchless -- it could be faster than the original, esp for higher frequencies.

Answer (score 0):

I imagine that it would work just fine your way (but don't forget to multiply by the amplitude):

```
buffer[frame] = sin(theta_increment * frame) * amplitude;
```

Just two different ways of expressing the same math. Looks like the person that wrote the original code wanted to keep 0 <= theta < 2pi, but this is probably not necessary (unless the sin() call is weird in a way I don't know about). Also, they might have wanted to keep the "math" part independent of the frame variable in case the same snippet shows up in other loops somewhere else, but that is just speculation.